# How can I load an image from the device gallery using Ionic and Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic application that uses Cordova and would like to load images from the album of the device. My problem is that it is not working, although I did follow the instructions on the Cordova website. Here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title>Ionic App</title>
        <link href="ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/slider-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/main-app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

        <script src="ionic/js/angular/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="ionic/js/angular/angular-animate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="ionic/js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/myapp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/LoadFromDevice.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </head>

    <body ng-app="ionicApp" animation="slide-left-right-ios7" ng-controller="PopupCtrl">

    <ion-nav-bar class="nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-light transparent-nav" style="background: none; border-bottom: none">
        <!--        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-chevron-left">
                </ion-nav-back-button>-->

    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view>

    </ion-nav-view>

</body>
</html>
```

**loadImage.html**

```
<button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
<button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
<img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
<img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
<script>


    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
      // Uncomment to view the base64-encoded image data
      // console.log(imageData);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }

    // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
    //
    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
      // Uncomment to view the image file URI
      // console.log(imageURI);

      // Get image handle
      //
      var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      largeImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The in-line CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhoto() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function capturePhotoEdit() {
      // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
    }

    // A button will call this function
    //
    function getPhoto(source) {
      // Retrieve image file location from specified source
      navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: source });
    }

    // Called if something bad happens.
    //
    function onFail(message) {
      alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    }


</script>
```

I am using the `cordova-plugin-camera` to achieve this.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: no error it just not working

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate more on 'just not working'. Which step in the process does it stop working?
a. Not finding the folder?
b. Unable to select the Photo from the folder?
c. Able to select the Photo but the URI is unavailable?
d. Available URI does not render correctly?

We might be able to help you based on your answer to the above as well as details on which device, OS version, cordova version, and ionic version you are in.

There are lots of variations and issues you need to handle to have this work across devices. There are some commercial plugins that do this well like https://www.onymos.com/products/media